# How to make ScrollViewer work only when texblock in it has height greater than ScrollViewer height?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

In my `ListBox` I show different content including text. Text can be long or short. It scrolls by `ScrollViewer`. Code:

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextsTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Texts}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

and it's also working if text is short, and height of this text do not reach `MaxHeight` of `ScrollViewer`. I want to make `ScrollViewer` works only when text is long and it's height greater than `ScrollViewer`'s `MaxHeight`, else - it doesn't have to work.

Tried border

```
<Border  BorderBrush="Aqua"  BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
 <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
 <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextsTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Texts}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
 </ScrollViewer>
 </Border>
```

but it's still scrolls in this border.

Comment: are you sure you want to set Grid.Column and Grid.Row values inside you ScrollViewr ??

Comment: i moved Grid.Column and Grid.Row values and set them to border, but it do not help(

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to [`Auto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The default value is `Visible` which means that the scroll bar is always shown.

By contrast the [`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has a default value of `Hidden`.

Comment: @eg01st - odd. I wonder if the `MaxHeight` value is affecting it. You could try wrapping the `ScrollViewer` in a `Border` (or similar) that has the `MaxHeight` property set.

Comment: It scrolls in vertical style

Answer (score 0):

Try removing some of the `Grid.` properties from the inner controls

```
<Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">       
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <TextBlock Text="text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

this works fine with one line of text

If I copy paste your code it works fine

[image]

Comment: well... i tried. When i set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` - whole text stand in one line, (i use `TextWrapping = "Wrap"` in textBlock) , if i remove `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`  text shows normal, but scroll still works(

Comment: So you tried the example I posted, because it works fine here. And if your `Wrapping` text you will have to set HorisontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled

Comment: even if you use the exact code I posted? perhaps the error is in your TextBlock style.

Comment: `<Style x:Key="TextsTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style> `   I dont think so

Comment: `<Border  BorderBrush="Aqua"  BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextsTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Texts}"  />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>`

Comment: hm... maybe because of wpf, not WP7?

Comment: maybe, it would be strange if WP7 scrolled controls by default, that would be terrible in a phone application

Comment: yep, so i want make them scrollable only when its realy need, but as i can see - it's not very easy(

Comment: how far does it scroll down with 1 line of text?

Comment: i think so far as i drag it) textblock has height just for this line, and if i start scrolling line - its disapear realy quicky, when i drop - it returns to base position